# Using hide() for the same element in different functions

Tags: jquery, hide

Alright this is my first day with JQuery so have fun with these functions I made. I'm trying to hide a div (#panel) when different triggers are clicked. Below is three functions in which all three of them need to hide (#panel) when used. The way I have it setup it's only working for the first function. The other two don't hide the element. So without further ado.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var $panel = $(this).closest(".panel-container").find(".panel");
$('#searchsubmit').click(function(e){
    $('#boxes').empty();
    e.preventDefault();
    var $panel = $(this).closest(".panel-container").find(".panel");
    var search_val=$("#s").val();
    $.post(
        WPaAjax.ajaxurl,
        {
            action : 'loop_search',
            search_val : search_val
        },
        function( response ) {
            $('#boxes').append( response ).masonry( 'reload' );
            $panel.hide("slow");
            $('.trigger').removeClass("active");
            $('.trigger-loop').removeClass("active");
        }
    );
});
$('#fame.trigger-loop').click(function(){
var $panel = $(this).closest(".panel-container").find(".panel");
    $('.trigger').removeClass('active');
    $('.trigger-loop').removeClass('active');
    $('#fame.trigger-loop').addClass('active');
    $('#boxes').empty();
    $.post(
        WPaAjax.ajaxurl,
        {
            action : 'loop_fame'
        },
        function( response ) {
            $('#boxes').append( response ).masonry( 'reload' );
            $panel.hide("slow");
        }
    );
});
$('#new.trigger-loop').click(function(){
var $panel = $(this).closest(".panel-container").find(".panel");
    $panel.hide("slow");
    $('.trigger').removeClass('active');
    $('.trigger-loop').removeClass('active');
    $('#new.trigger-loop').addClass('active');
    $('#boxes').empty();
    $.post(
        WPaAjax.ajaxurl,
        {
            action : 'loop_new',
        },
        function( response ) {
            $('#boxes').append( response ).masonry( 'reload' );
            $panel.hide("slow");
        }
    );
 });

});
```

//--html

```
<li>
 <a id="fame" class="trigger-loop active" href="#"><div id="fame-icon"></div></a>
</li>
<li>
 <a id="new" class="trigger-loop" href="#"><div id="gold-artist"></div></a>
</li>
<li>
 <div class="panel-container">
  <div class="panel">
     <----content----->
  </div>
  <a class="trigger" href="#"><div id="playlist-icon"></div></a>
 </div>
</li>
<li>
 <div class="panel-container">
  <div class="panel">
     <----content----->
  </div>
  <a class="trigger" href="#"><div id="random-icon"></div></a>
 </div>
</li>
```

Comment: can you provide a part of your HTML

Comment: if your panel has `id="panel"`, you can access it as `$('#panel')`, don't need to worry about closest/find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a global variable which is being overwritten and causing undesired affects.

```
var $panel = $(this).closest(".panel-container").find(".panel");
```

That line will set `$panel` as a global variable since it has no parent scope aside from `document.ready`. When you are inside one of the callback closures, there is a conflict of interest when `$panel` is defined again. Consider changing these names to remove the conflict.

The result is calling the global `$panel` when inside of

```
function( response ) {
        $('#boxes').append( response ).masonry( 'reload' );
        $panel.hide("slow");
 }
```

instead of calling the localized version you were thinking of. That is why only one of them is hiding.

Comment: @Utkanos - See my edit at the bottom, `function(response){}` is accessing the global variable `$panel` and not the variable defined in the click callback's closure.

Comment: Ok I just drastically misinterpreted something I read. I just used $('.panel').hide() instead.

Comment: @TravisJ - I'm intrigued as to why you think the global variable would be referenced. In each event callback, he overwrites the variable with a local version, and it's that one that the AJAX callback, when created, would capture in its closure. Thus the AJAX callbacks would always reference the local `$panel`, never the global one, surely.

Answer (score 0):

try this for both `$('#fame.trigger-loop').click` and `$('#new.trigger-loop').click`;

```
var $panel = $(this).closest('ul').find(".panel-container").find(".panel");
```

Comment: If you look inside of the response callback for the post, you will see that no matter what the local `$panel` is defined as, it will never be accessed. It may as well be `undefined`.